# Plant or flower growing in pot

Tags: flowering

Northern Indiana growing in pot. Anyone know what type of plant or flower this might be? Approximately 2’ tall so far

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDnG.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDnG.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFpoX.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the leaf shape, you have a couple of cottonwood trees (*Populus deltoides*) growing in your pot. I had the same thing a few years ago - I was trying for aspens and wound up with cottonwoods (they're cousins, kind of). To confirm my answer, just wait a few weeks: the leaves should have absolutely no fall color and just turn brown, with a leathery feel.